# continuity of an implicit function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

For some continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}_+^2\to \mathbb{R}_+$ and $k$ a positive integer, I know that the equation
$$
g=(1+f(g,x))^k,
$$
where the unknown is $g$, has a unique root when $x$ is taken from $[a,b]$ with $0<a<b<1$. This implicitely defines a function $g(x)$, over $[a,b]$. Can I conclude that $g(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is bounded, yes:

Let $F(g, x) = (1 + f(g, x))^k$, then $F$ is also continuous and also provides unique roots $g$ for each $x$. $F$ is also bounded, and thus $g$ must be bounded as well. If $\lim_n x_n = x$ and $\lim_n g(x_n) = u$, then by the continuity of $F$, $$F(u, x) = F(\lim_n g(x_n), \lim_n x_n) = \lim_n F(g(x_n), x_n) = \lim_n g(x_n) = u$$
Hence $u = g(x)$. Now for a more arbitrary $\{x_n\}$ converging to $x$, $g(x)$ is the only possible limit point for $\{g(x_n)\}$. But a bounded sequence must have a limit point, and if there is only one, it must converge to it. Hence $g$ is sequentially continuous, which in $\Bbb R$ is equivalent to continuity.

I'm out of time to examine the case when $f$ is not bounded.

Comment: I'm sorry: how do you know that $g(x)$ is the only possible limit point for $\{g(x_n)\}$?

Comment: Because I've already shown that all convergent sequences of the form $\{g(x_n)\}$ converge to $g(x)$. An arbitrary sequence contains subsequences that converge to each of its limit points (otherwise, they wouldn't be limit points). But these subsequences must all have limit $g(x)$. So it is the only possible limit point. Of course, in general a sequence doesn't have to have limit points at all, which is why I needed the boundedness condition.